# Get all DocuSign EnvelopeIds that originated from a powerform

Tags: docusignapi

Using DocuSign's REST API, is there a way to retrieve a list of all envelope Ids from an account where the envelopes have a completed status and originated from a specific power form?

I've tried using the follow call and still see all completed envelopes after 9/12 regardless of where they originated from:

GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1655678/envelopes?from_date=2016-09-12&powerformids=2fc0a56d-f6c7-4e96-be93-258d0c038e3c&status=completed HTTP/1.1

The best working solution I have now is to add a custom field to the envelope and filter on it using the custom_field parameter. This requires additional setup from users and is not optimal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at DocuSign Connect for this?  If you setup a specific user for your Powerform, Connect can publish events to you for just the envelopes created from that user.  Then you wouldn't even need to make calls to get the Envelope IDs (or even other information).

Answer (score 0):

- Your idea of adding a custom field on the template level is the best way to go. It will help return accurate results, though I would agree it adds some overhead/upkeep during template/powerform creation.
- The powerformids parameter you are including in your sample is not a supporter parameter and is simply being ignored.